# Restructuring DataFrame to match value with other column number

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe

```
Name  Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4  Rank5
Name1  Title1  Title3  Title7  Title2  Title6
Name2  Title3  Title2  Title6  Title5  Title4
Name3  Title2  Title5  Title3  Title6  Title4
Name4  Title4  Title6  Title1  Title5  Title2
```

and I would like to make the dataframe look like this

```
    Name  Title1  Title2  Title3  Title4  Title5  Title6  Title7
    Name1       1       4       2      10      10       5       3
    Name2      10       2       1       4       4       3      10
    Name3      10       1       3       5       2       4      10
    Name4       3       5      10       1       4       2      10
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to 2 columns, [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the number from the rank, [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to wide format with titles as columns:

```
out = (df.melt('Name')
         .assign(Rank=lambda d: d['variable'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$', expand=False).astype(int))
         .pivot_table(index='Name', columns='value', values='Rank', fill_value=10)
         .rename_axis(columns=None). reset_index()
      )
```

More robust variant to keep the original index and handle sorting of the columns for titles > "Title 9":

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsort_key

out = (df.melt('Name', ignore_index=False).reset_index()
         .assign(Rank=lambda d: d['variable'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$', expand=False).astype(int))
         .pivot_table(index=['index', 'Name'], columns='value', values='Rank', fill_value=10)
         .sort_index(axis=1, key=natsort_key)
         .reset_index('Name').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
    Name  Title1  Title2  Title3  Title4  Title5  Title6  Title7
0  Name1       1       4       2      10      10       5       3
1  Name2      10       2       1       5       4       3      10
2  Name3      10       1       3       5       2       4      10
3  Name4       3       5      10       1       4       2      10
```

Comment: The first example worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben which error? Can you provide a DataFrame constructor to reproduce it?

Comment: I was able to track down my error. My data had a number for the column header (1 not Rank1), so I had to change the rank format in my initial data.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: In this case you should add `var_name='Rank'` to `melt` and remove the `assign`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
def find_rank(row, v):
    rank = np.where(row == v)[0]
    if len(rank) == 0:
        return 10
    else:
        return rank[0]

for v in ['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4', 'Title5', 'Title6']:
    df[v] = df.apply(find_rank, v = v, axis = 1)

df = df.drop(['Rank1', 'Rank2', 'Rank3', 'Rank4', 'Rank5'], axis = 1)
```

This code finds the value and returns its index for each row. 
 If there is no value in a row, then it returns 10.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with numpy (a bit weary to flip and unflip - worried about the costs - just a hunch, and i may be wrong) - and then recreating the final dataframe

```py
columns = ['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4', 'Title5', 'Title6', 'Title7']
out = (df
       .set_index('Name')
       .apply(lambda x: x.str[-1])
       .astype(int)
      )
# get the positions within each row
sort_indices = out.apply(np.argsort,axis=1, raw=True).to_numpy()
# get column positions, starting from zero
# and reorder them based on sort_indices
length = len(out)
positions = out.to_numpy()-1
positions = positions[np.arange(length)[:, None], sort_indices]

# create new array that will contain the properly positioned values:
arr = np.empty(shape=(length, len(columns)),dtype=float)
arr[:] = np.nan
arr[np.arange(length)[:, None], positions] = sort_indices

# increase value by 1
# fill nulls with 10
# create dataframe
arr += 1
arr = np.where(np.isnan(arr), 10, arr).astype(int)
(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=columns, index=out.index)
# avoid reset_index if you can,
# indexes are good, use them when possible
.reset_index()
)

    Name  Title1  Title2  Title3  Title4  Title5  Title6  Title7
0  Name1       1       4       2      10      10       5       3
1  Name2      10       2       1       5       4       3      10
2  Name3      10       1       3       5       2       4      10
3  Name4       3       5      10       1       4       2      10
```